# Gsheet howto export range to report and track changed values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Objective: when importing new values, I need to keep tracks of old values in a new spreadsheet by adding the snapshot with the date and time of the export.

I have an array (columns A:C) below to export in a other spreadsheet (will stay the same):

[image: array to export]

In the scenario for the exported spreadsheet below, I would like a script doing this similar information exported based on the date of the export :

[image: exported spreadsheet]

- 1 is the previous export
- 2 is the new export that goes in the next column after the previous export with the now date.
- 3 the next exported values
- 4 the values exported from column C depending on when the export have been done.

The model file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/163LW8Gb0KtgE2yvLe_D6wpyUcjbPWYiyxIrEbFNoNfM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your help

Comment: (1) Your spreadsheet cannot be accessed, can you make it publicly accessible? (remove sensitive information), (2) Where does the data come from? I guess there's a single source sheet that gets updated, and that's where the data is coming from? (3) So, instead of `Population`, you want your headers to be the date when that column was imported?

Comment: (1)The link could now be public [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tkRG6tyO-07fBG52IPt4nQE1Nr3x4MBRuvXvTjbuNAU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: (2) from import of an excel file to a transit gsheet than a importrange to the colum A:C that make them the same with no change. (3) correct, as we know that is about population. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Get the list of source cities and of previously exported cities, using [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Iterate through the source cities, finding the row index to which is corresponds in the target sheet (appending the city if it doesn't already exist in the target sheet).
- Export the data via [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

#### Code sample:

```
const FIRST_ROW = 2;

function exportData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  const target = ss.getSheetByName("exported");
  const sourceValues = source.getRange("A2:C" + source.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const currentExportedCities = target.getRange("A2:B" + target.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let exportedPopulation = new Array(currentExportedCities.length).fill("");
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    const [control, city, population] = sourceValues[i];
    let cityIndex = currentExportedCities.map(c => c[1]).indexOf(city);
    if (cityIndex < 0) {
      currentExportedCities.push([control,city]);
      cityIndex = currentExportedCities.length-1;
    }
    exportedPopulation[cityIndex] = population;
  };
  target.getRange(FIRST_ROW, 1, currentExportedCities.length, currentExportedCities[0].length).setValues(currentExportedCities);
  exportedPopulation.unshift(new Date());
  target.getRange(1, target.getLastColumn() + 1, exportedPopulation.length).setValues(exportedPopulation.map(p => [p]));
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank Iamblichus it woks.

Comment: Something that i did not mention is that I need to capture column A as well that will have data for each week that will be add during the year.

Comment: @Thierry I updated the code sample to capture column A too.

Comment: Sorry lamblichus I should have been more accurate as i try to applied it in my massive sheet but got error because of the column.

Comment: @Thierry I'm not sure I understand your problem now, but I'd suggest you to post a new question for this.